# Missing input example Error in convert Pythorch model to Onnx

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, onnx, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to change the pytorch-lightning model, (ckpt) to onnx with the following code:
................

```
test_comment = 'I am still waiting on my card?'

start= time.time()

encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(
  test_comment,
  add_special_tokens=True,
  max_length=512,
  return_token_type_ids=False,
  padding="max_length",
  return_attention_mask=True,
  return_tensors='pt',
)

input_ids = encoding["input_ids"]
attention_mask =  encoding["attention_mask"]


trained_model.to_onnx( "model_lightnining_export.onnx",
                       (input_ids.unsqueeze(dim=0), attention_mask.unsqueeze(dim=0)) , export_params=True ,
                       input_names=['images'],
                       output_names=['output'])
```

And get the following **error** (although I did put the attention_mask as a example input):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-240-853786b1ab45> in <module>
     22                        (input_ids.unsqueeze(dim=0), attention_mask.unsqueeze(dim=0)) , export_params=True ,
     23                        input_names=['images'],
---> 24                        output_names=['output'])
     25 

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             Module: self
    726         """
--> 727         return self._apply(lambda t: t.xpu(device))
    728 
    729     def cpu(self: T) -> T:

TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attention_mask'
```

The code of the model:

```
class Tagger(pl.LightningModule):

  def __init__(self, n_classes: int, n_training_steps=None, n_warmup_steps=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained(BERT_MODEL_NAME, return_dict=True)
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, n_classes)
    self.n_training_steps = n_training_steps
    self.n_warmup_steps = n_warmup_steps
    self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction="mean")
    self.n_classes = n_classes
    self.activation = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, labels=None):
    output = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    output = self.classifier(output.pooler_output)
    output = torch.relu(output)
    loss = 0
    if labels is not None:
        loss = self.criterion(output, labels)
    return loss, output

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("train_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return {"loss": loss, "predictions": outputs, "labels": labels}

  def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("val_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

  def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("test_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

  def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    
    labels = []
    predictions = []
    for output in outputs:
      for out_labels in output["labels"].detach().cpu():
        labels.append(out_labels)
      for out_predictions in output["predictions"].detach().cpu():
        predictions.append(out_predictions)

    labels = torch.stack(labels).int()
    predictions = torch.stack(predictions)

  def configure_optimizers(self):

    optimizer = AdamW(self.parameters(), lr=2e-5)

    scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
      optimizer,
      num_warmup_steps=self.n_warmup_steps,
      num_training_steps=self.n_training_steps
    )

    return dict(
      optimizer=optimizer,
      lr_scheduler=dict(
        scheduler=scheduler,
        interval='step'
      )
    )
```

Ideas for further optimization for predicting the Bert model in production are welcome.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the onnx exporter that your model has two inputs:

```py
(input_ids.unsqueeze(dim=0), attention_mask.unsqueeze(dim=0))
```

but then you only have one input name:

```py
input_names=['images']
```

you should write the following:

```py
trained_model.to_onnx( "model_lightnining_export.onnx",
                       (input_ids.unsqueeze(dim=0), attention_mask.unsqueeze(dim=0)) , export_params=True ,
                       input_names=['input_ids', 'attention_mask'],
                       output_names=['output'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `trained_model` is an element of the class `Tagger`, I believe that it will be easier for you to use `attention_mask` as an attribute of your Tagger class. So in `Tagger.__init__()` add an argument `attention_mask` and a line `self.attention_mask = attention_mask`.
Then in forward, remove it from the arguments and only use `output = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=self.attention_mask)`.
Finally, in your conversion code, you may initialize your trained_model with the extra parameter `attention_mask =  encoding["attention_mask"]`

This may better work as most of the converter to scripts/onnx only accept one input : the input tensor, and here you try with a tensor and an attention mask

Comment: He throws me this error, where else do I need to change? `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

TypeError: forward() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`